# corrgram package dependencies

Tags: r

I have installed R 3.3.2, compiled from source in Ubuntu 14.04. I tried to install corrgram package like

1) `install.packages("corrgram")`

2) `devtools::install_github("kwstat/corrgram")`

but a number of dependency errors a showed.
There are dependencies like `seriation, dedextend, fpc, flexmix` and have no idea what these packages are.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The reason for its occurrence was a package installation problem for the `nloptr` package in the 'dependency-chain' of `corrgram`. I could solve it by manually installing

> sudo apt-get install libnlopt-dev

as described here: [Installing nloptr on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716857/installing-nloptr-on-linux)